# Is that true that plant stem cells can be used in humans?

Tags: human-biology, plant-physiology, stem-cells

I was reading an [article](http://allintoendadolescentaids.org/penis-enlargement/stem-cell-penis-enlargement/) (which seems very fake to me) on sensitive topics, but there was one astonishing statement:

> Stem cells are obtained from certain plants that grow all over the world. Once the stem cells have been obtained, the doctor will inject them on the target organ...

I want to ask specialists if this particular statement can be true. If yes, does it imply nucleus replacement in stem cells, or anything like that?

Sorry guys, for the stupid question.

Comment: They very likely can't be used. The number of chromosomes won't match and most likely the immune system will mount a response against the plant cells

Comment: Absolutely not, plants do not have the same signal pathways and have very different cell biology.

Comment: Of course, the stem cells must be obtained from the plant stems ;-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is very poor quality and under researched.

Comment: @tyersome, poor quality? It's readable - yes. Under researched? You wish to answer only clever and obvious school-test grade questions? If everyone had the knowledge, no questions would be needed. Don't like this question - don't spend your time here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stemcells.nih.gov/info/basics/6.htm
...
Viruses are currently used to introduce the reprogramming factors into adult cells, and this process must be carefully controlled and tested before the technique can lead to useful treatment for humans. In animal studies, the virus used to introduce the stem cell factors sometimes causes cancers. Researchers are currently investigating non-viral delivery strategies. In any case, this breakthrough discovery has created a powerful new way to "de-differentiate" cells whose developmental fates had been previously assumed to be determined. In addition, tissues derived from iPSCs will be a nearly identical match to the cell donor and thus probably avoid rejection by the immune system. The iPSC strategy creates pluripotent stem cells that, together with studies of other types of pluripotent stem cells, will help researchers learn how to reprogram cells to repair damaged tissues in the human body.

So as that all points out, no, the genetics of it will cause a plant stem cell to be genetically not a match, where it might do something for a little while, but upon that cells first interactions, it will stimulate the immune system to get rid of it, rather than incorporate it.
Anymore, I want to know about how Bone Morphinogenic Proteins (BMP-4 or above) can be injected into an organ, and if that will help stem cells for reviving an organ at all.